# Can clang detect IBActionAttr in iOS?

Tags: ios, clang, abstract-syntax-tree, static-analysis, llvm-clang

I've dumped out the contents of the AST for Objective C methods and some of the methods have a IBActionAttr as its child.

However, IBActionAttr is not a Stmt or Decl. How should I go about detecting if the ObjCMethodDecl has an IBActionAttr?

Answer (score 1):

Use the method `hasAttr<IBActionAttr>()` from `Decl` works fine

`Decl->hasAttr<IBActionAttr>()` returns true if Decl has attribute `IBActionAttr`